# Iterate primefaces datatable row using jquery

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, primefaces

I have primefaces data table with 5 page. each page have 10 records. i  need to iterate all 50 records using jquery. 
i shoudn't not use this - $(#id).datatable().fnGetNodes()-

I have used foreach for tr but it only giving current page row.

Is  there any other way we can achieve it?

Comment: What DataTables version are you using?

Comment: primefaces 5.2.5 <P;datatable>

Comment: Function `fnGetNodes` is used by jQuery DataTables but [PrimeFaces DataTable](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/basic.xhtml) is completely different library.

Comment: Can you help me out how to iterate prieface datatable using jquery

Comment: My requirement is when the user clicks on the command button i need to check the data table 2nd column value in all page whether particular value is present. based on the that i need to invoke managed bean method

Comment: Why don't you check it in a bean method?